# Problems with Jinja not executing python code within a block

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a basic web app - a blog - I am trying to create using Flask.

I am trying to use `{{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}` in my `index.html` to create a dynamic url. However, I am continually getting a GET request error because Jinja is not recognizing it as python code, and Flask is trying to create a url using the verbatim call.

Here is an example error:

```
"GET /%7B‌%20%7Burl_for(%22static%22,%20filename=%22vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css%22)%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404
```

The problem is not with the url_for() call or with the structure of my directory/inclusion of correct static and template folders because using

```
with app.test_request_context():
    print(url_for('static', filename='vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'))
```

in my `main.py` file prints the correct path.

Additionally, Jinja is properly installed and working as evidenced by the fact that `{% include "header.html" %}` and `{% include "footer.html" %}` both work because the attempts to create the urls are all in those files.

Here is my `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')


with app.test_request_context():
    print(url_for('static', filename='vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the relevant part of  `index.html`

```
{% include "header.html"%}

<!-- Page Header -->
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/img/home-bg.jpg')">
...
</header>

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
...
</div>

{% include "footer.html"%}
```

Here is the `footer.html` :

```
<!-- Footer -->
 <footer>
 ...
 </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='js/clean-blog.min.js') }}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the `header.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}} " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='css/clean-blog.min.css')}} " rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    ...
  </nav>
```

One last note, before created the dynamic urls and doing a static reference, all the CSS/JS files rendered correctly.

**Edit**

The following code correctly renders the url on the page.

`<h1>{{url_for('static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', _external=True)}}</h1>`

It's only when I wrap it as a string that it no longer picks it up as code.

Comment: `url_for('static', filename='vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css', _external=True)`

Comment: Jinja is not executing the code within the block, so adding an additional parameter won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the content you've pasted in your question, there is a Unicode [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character in between the two `{` markers in front of your Jinja expression.  That is, if I copy this line from `footer.html`:

```
  <script src="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

And produce a hexdump from it, I see:

```
00000000: 2020 3c73 6372 6970 7420 7372 633d 227b    <script src="{
00000010: e280 8c7b 2075 726c 5f66 6f72 2827 7374  ...{ url_for('st
00000020: 6174 6963 272c 2066 696c 656e 616d 653d  atic', filename=
00000030: 2776 656e 646f 722f 6a71 7565 7279 2f6a  'vendor/jquery/j
00000040: 7175 6572 792e 6d69 6e2e 6a73 2729 207d  query.min.js') }
00000050: 7d22 3e3c 2f73 6372 6970 743e 0a         }"></script>.
```

Look at offset `x10`, where we see `e2 80 8c`; that's the UTF-8 encoding of U+200c:

```
>>> "\u200c".encode()
b'\xe2\x80\x8c'
```

If I remove those extraneous characters from your source, everything works correctly:

```
$ curl -s localhost:5000 | grep static

  <link href="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/static/css/clean-blog.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/img/home-bg.jpg')">
  This is a test /static/foo/bar
  <script src="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: They aren't extraneous characters though. The instructor of the course indicated that I will need to have dynamic urls later in the project, which is why I am trying to use url_for(). Is there any way to only remove the character between the two markers that is causing the error? Should I change the encoding?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. The output you see at the bottom there is the *output from the web application*. I was demonstrating that simply removing the extraneous characters correct the problem, and it is now calling `url_for` properly.

Comment: You could explicitly look for occurrences of that character: `grep -lr $'\u200c' *` Or even correct the problem from the command line: `sed -i $'s/\u200c//g' file1 file ...`

Comment: Why was the character inserted in the first place? If that requires too long of an answer, then what situations would this happen in?

Comment: I'm not able to answer that question: you'd have to ask whoever created the examples. Sometimes one sees something like that if someone tries writing code samples with a word processor instead of a text editor, but that more oftens shows up as erroneous typographer's quotes or em- or en-dashes instead of hyphens.